# RabbitMQ connection with multiple URIs

Tags: rabbitmq, ssl, amqp

While

```
ConnectionFactory.newConnection(Address[] addrs)
```

and thus

```
ConnectionFactory.newConnection(
  Address.parseAddresses("somehost.com:5672,otherhost.com:5672"))
```

work, I was wondering if there was a way to pass multiple URIs like:

```
ConectionFactory.newConnection("amqps://somehost.com:5671,amqps://otherhost.com:5671")
```

Or to allow potentially different client certificates for each URI, first create multiple ConnectionFactories, each with one URI and then create a ConnectionFactory that takes those connection factories as inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this is not possible.  http://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html

If you are trying to implement failover, you might consider something like heartbeat: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Simple_IP_Failover_with_Heartbeat

If you are trying to read messages from multiple places, you can use shovel (http://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) to bring these messages from multiple places into one queue and read from that.

Comment: For Python(Nameko) based approach one can us [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830888/rabbitmq-client-load-balancing/48744714#48744714)