# How load balancer works in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, load-balancing

I am new to RabbitMQ, so please excuse me for asking some trivial questions:

1. When running a RabbitMQ cluster, if a node fails the load shifts to another node (without stopping the other nodes). Similarly, we can also add new nodes to the existing cluster without stopping existing nodes in the cluster. Is that correct?
2. Assume that we start with a single RabbitMQ node, and create 100 queues on it. Now let's say that producers start sending messages at a faster rate. To handle this load, we add more nodes and make a cluster. But queues exist on the first node only. How does the load get balanced among nodes now? And if we need to add more queues, on which node should we add them? Or can we add them using the load balancer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> 1. When running a RabbitMQ cluster, if a node fails the load shifts to another node (without stopping the other nodes). Similarly, we can also add new nodes to the existing cluster without stopping existing nodes in the cluster. Is that correct?

If a node on which the queue was created fails, RabbitMQ will elect a new master for that queue in the cluster as long as mirroring for the queue is enabled. Clustering provides high availability (HA) based on a policy that you can define.

> 2. Assume that we start with a single RabbitMQ node, and create 100 queues on it. Now let's say that producers start sending messages at a faster rate. To handle this load, we add more nodes and make a cluster. But queues exist on the first node only. How does the load get balanced among nodes now?

The load is not balanced. The distributed cluster provides high availability and not load balancing. Your requests will be redirected to the node in the cluster on which the queue resides.

> And if we need to add more queues, on which node should we add them? Or can we add them using the load balancer?

That depends on your use case. Some folks use a round robin and create queues on separate nodes.

#### In summary

- For high availability, use [mirroring](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) in the cluster.
- To balance load across nodes, use a [load balancer (LB) to distribute across Queues](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/11/17/load-balancing-a-rabbitmq-cluster/comment-page-1/).
- If you'd like to load balance the queue itself take a look at [federated queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federated-queues.html). They allow you to fetch messages on a downstream queue from an upstream queue.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your questions in a way that will help most developers.

> **Question 1.** When running a RabbitMQ cluster, if a node fails the load shifts to another node (without stopping the other nodes). Similarly, we can also add new nodes to the existing cluster without stopping existing nodes in the cluster. Is that correct?

You are absolutely correct, assuming RabbitMQ is running on a single host, but RabbitMQ's queue behaves differently in the cluster. By default, each queue lives on only one node in the cluster. As of Rabbit 2.6.0, however, we have a built-in active-active redundancy option for queues: **mirrored queues**. Declaring a mirrored queue is just like declaring a normal queue, but you pass an extra argument called `x-ha-policy`. The extra argument tells RabbitMQ that you want the queue to be mirrored across all nodes in the cluster. **This means that if a new node is added to the cluster after the queue is declared, it'll automatically begin hosting a slave copy of the queue.**

> **Question 2.** Assume that we start with a single RabbitMQ node, and create 100 queues on it. Now let's say that producers start sending messages at a faster rate. To handle this load, we add more nodes and make a cluster. But queues exist on the first node only. How does the load get balanced among nodes now? And if we need to add more queues, on which node should we add them? Or can we add them using the load balancer?

This question has multiple sub-questions.

> How does the load get balanced among nodes now? On which node should we add the queues?

Set to all, `x-ha-policy` tells RabbitMQ that you want the queue to be mirrored across all nodes in the cluster. This means that if a new node is added to the cluster after the queue is declared, it'll automatically begin hosting a slave copy of the queue.

> Can we add the queues using a load balancer?

You shouldn't, although you technically can (you would have to call the RabbitMQ API within a LB, which is not a good practice). A load balancer is used for resilient messaging infrastructure. Your cluster nodes are the servers behind the load balancer, and your producers and consumers are the customers.

Comment: Do we really need a Load balancer like HA Proxy for RabbitMQ cluster?

Comment: There is no one-line answer, but mostly for critical project yes, you did need.